# Accessing Nested POST Parameters in Java

Tags: java, servlets, post, url-parameters

How do I access nested POST data in the Java Servlet API? In PHP (which I can't use for this project), I was able to access fields with `$ds = $_POST['details']['double_sided'];`

I have the following inputs in my form:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="details_double_sided" class="control-label">
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="<portlet:namespace />details[double_sided]">
                <input type="checkbox" id="details_double_sided" value="1" name="<portlet:namespace />details[double_sided]"> Double Sided
            </label>

            <label for="details_stapled" class="control-label">
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="<portlet:namespace />details[stapled]">
                <input type="checkbox" id="details_stapled" value="1" name="<portlet:namespace />details[stapled]"> Stapled
            </label>

            <label for="details_three_hole_punched" class="control-label">
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="<portlet:namespace />details[three_hole_punched]">
                <input type="checkbox" id="details_three_hole_punched" value="1" name="<portlet:namespace />details[three_hole_punched]"> Three Hole Punched
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="details_copied_in_color" class="control-label">
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="<portlet:namespace />details[copied_in_color]">
                <input type="checkbox" id="details_copied_in_color" value="1" name="<portlet:namespace />details[copied_in_color]"> Copied in Color
            </label>

            <label for="details_copied_on_color_page" class="control-label">
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="<portlet:namespace />details[copied_on_color_page]">
                <input type="checkbox" id="details_copied_on_color_page" value="1" name="<portlet:namespace />details[copied_on_color_page]"> Copied on Color Paper (Please indicate paper color in special instructions)
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried multiple methods, such as

```
String[] details = ParamUtil.get(request, "details[double_sided]", "0")

Object details = request.getAttribute("details");

String[] details = ParamUtil.getParameterValues(request, "details[]");
```

But they all seem to return null / empty values.

Comment: What web framework are you using ?
Whatever you use I suggest using any serialization mechanism it provides.

Comment: have you tried request.getParameter("details[double_sided]"); (assuming that it is referenced by name and not id)

Answer (score 0):

The function `getParameter()` requires the name of the field that you input, which your code is `<portlet:namespace />details[double_sided]`.

If this doesn't work, you can get all the parameter names that have been passed to your servlet with `getParameterNames()` which you can iterate over to check your inputs, or `getParameterMap` which is map containing all the keys and values that have been posted to your servlet.